# convert binary string to hex value

Tags: node.js, express, binary, hex, buffer

I'm working on my Web Server using Node JS and Express.js. I need to insert hex value in a Buffer, starting from a binary string. My code is something like this:

```
var buffer = fs.readFileSync("myBINfile.dat");   
setValue(buffer, 4);


function setValue(buffer, i) {

  var value1 = parseInt(buffer[i].toString(16), 16).toString(2).toString()
  value1 = "0" + value1.substring(1, value1.length);

  var hex = parseInt(value1, 2).toString(16); 

  console.log(hex); // print a8 (correct)

  buffer[i] = hex;

  console.log(buffer[i]); // print 0 (why?)

}
```

The buffer contains a hex file. `value1` is read correctly. How can fix this this problem?
Thanks

Comment: *"Hex Buffer and `i` are previusly defined and they are valid."* - Can you show that? because otherwise, this code is fine, and testing it works as expected.

Comment: And you're sure this is your latest code? (note your comment says `// print a8 (correct)`, but this _can't_ print `a8` as `value1 = "0" + value1.substring(1, value1.length);` prefixes whatever value would be in there with a 0)

Comment: I was wrong to update. It seems a simple operation but something is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing a string value into your `Buffer` object rather than a numerical value that it expects. Replace the line:

```js
var hex = parseInt(value1, 2).toString(16);
```

with:

```js
var hex = parseInt(value1, 2);
```

`"a8"` is really just the integer value 168 (you'll find if you `console.log(value1)` before your `var hex = parseInt(value1, 2).toString(16);` line, you'll get `10101000` (168 in binary)). When you write this value to the buffer, you really just want to write the integer value, not the string `"a8"`.

The "hex value" as you put it, is actually just a number, hex is simply a presentation format. You don't store "hex numbers" or "binary numbers", you just store the numbers themselves.

As a result doing this you'll find `console.log(hex);` outputs 168 instead and think "That's wrong though!", but it's not, because 168 *is* a8.

---

The reason why you'll find it works with some values but not others is because any values which result in a purely numerical hex value (e.g. `"22"` or `"67"`) will be automatically converted the their numerical equivalent (`22` or `67`). In your case however `"a8"` the value cannot be converted to the number type required by the buffer and so is discarded and `0` is written.